# I cant remove the error "Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'User'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User'"

Tags: typescript, prisma

```
export interface User {
  id: string
  name: string
  bio: string
  public_repos: string
  public_gists: string
}
```

```
async function getPrismaUser(
  ctx: Context,
  githubUserId: string,
): Promise<User> {
  return await ctx.prisma.user.findOne({ where: { githubUserId } })
}
```

I've tried adding non-null assertion checks in my return statement but the error doesn't go away. Is my only solution "strict": false in tsconfig.json?

Comment: Where is that error being shown? Also, where is your non-null check?

Comment: `findOne` may return `null`. If you add a check for this and throw an exception in your function when it's `null`, the error will go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `findOne()` is `User | null` (with a few conditions, see below). That union type doesn't match the return type of your function `getPrismaUser()` which is `User`.

To fix your error, change the return type of `getPrismaUser()` to `User | null`.

> findOne returns a plain old JavaScript object or null.
>
> The type of the object that's returned by a findOne API call depends
>   on whether you use the select and include options.
>
> If you use neither of these options, the return type will correspond
>   to the TypeScript type that's generated for the model.

From the [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/crud#return-type).

Comment: While it isn't what the OP asked, I'll add that they ought to handle that `null` return type possibility somewhere.